# Swift viewController launch unity scene

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, swift2

I am currently working on a swift+unity project. Swift or Unity-iOS works fine, and also imported swift code into Unity-iOS workspace. Then I created a button in one of my viewControllers.swift, but how can I open unity scene when clicking that button?

BTW, I am using swift2+unity5

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event on the button. If the button is clicked, application.Loadlevel(x). You can find out the level number or name by clicking on file -> build settings, then add your scene to the build. You can use the name or the number of the scene.